# R Shiny ggvis add_legend issue

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I am working on an interactive shiny plot where the user can select what they want on each axis, and the attribute that colours the points.

For simplicity, I have provided a dummy data set here:

```
test_df <-tibble(test_x = sample(c(1:100), 10),
                 test_y = sample(c(1:100), 10),
                 variable = rep(c("A", "B"), 5),
                 colour = rep(c("orange", "green"), 5))
```

The following code works fine (and also works for my real reactive plot, which is a lot more complex and has additional arguments):

```
test_df %>%
  ggvis(x = ~test_x, y = ~test_y, fill:= ~colour) %>%
  layer_points()
```

However, as soon as I try to add in the legend (using `add_legend()`), the plot produced is blank. It does **not** produce error messages (neither in this dummy code nor the real example). Code used is:

```
test_df %>%
  ggvis(x = ~test_x, y = ~test_y, fill:= ~colour) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  add_legend(scales = "fill", title = "blah")
```

I have attempted to use the information provided in the following issues plus the help information, but with no luck.

[ggvis interactive figure does not work as expected using reactive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523268/ggvis-interactive-figure-does-not-work-as-expected-using-reactive-values)

[ggvis output not appearing in shiny application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957676/ggvis-output-not-appearing-in-shiny-application)

I feel like I am missing something very obvious, so any advice or guidance would be very appreciated. I also am aware that the shiny version will require more complexity in the code, but I feel if I can get it working locally first this will help me figure out the next step.

Note: I need to use ggvis to enable hover over tooltips. I know this can be done simply using other graphical packages, but I need the ggvis answer.

Thank you!

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `fill= ~colour`. It works for me otherwise.

Comment: @kluu thank you for your response. However, I need to have the specific colours listed in that column for those points, hence the colon. Without the colon I get the wrong colours assigned to the points.

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't even check the colors outputed.

Comment: @kluu no problem! It took me a while to get that bit figured out anyway :) Any ideas otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out why your code doesn't work. Maybe it's just that it's not meant to be used this way. The only workaround I found is the one below, but I'm pretty sure something better can be done.

```
test_df %>%
  ggvis(x = ~test_x, y = ~test_y, fill = ~colour) %>%
  add_legend(scales = "fill", title = "blah") %>%
  scale_ordinal("fill", range = unique(test_df$colour)) %>%
  layer_points()
```

Comment: Thanks @kluu! In a way it is a slight relief to know that I was not just missing something obvious! This solution works for the dummy dataset, so I will see if it works for my more complex example. Thanks once again!

Comment: Ok so this solution works in a way; it doesn't break the plot (huzzah). However, with my real example I only see the legend of the title and no content. So it is a step forward!

I think the issue now is to due with how the reactives etc are interacting. But thank you for your help!

Comment: So the final piece of the puzzle to get this work for my actual shiny use-case is to include the equivalent of `domain = unique(test_df$variable)` within the `scale_ordinal()` function.